# MKPolyline won't display

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I'm trying to get my MKPolyline to display, I think I have most everything right, but I must be missing something. No error codes, the map displays fine otherwise and I can drop annotation pins just fine.

the .h

```
@interface SatFinderViewController: UIViewController 
<MKMapViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet MKOverlayView *mapView;
IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
MKMapView *_mapView;
MKPolyline *_routeLine;
MKPolylineView *_routeLineView;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKAnnotationView *mapAView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKOverlayView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView;

-(void)calculate;
-(void)loadRoute;

@end
```

The .m

```
-(void)calculate
{ ...

[map removeOverlay:self.routeLine];
self.routeLine = nil;   
[self loadRoute];
[map addOverlay:routeLine];
[map setNeedsDisplay];

}

-(void) loadRoute
{
SatFinderAppDelegate *appdel = (SatFinderAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
float s = [appdel.location floatValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D *locations = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * 2);

CLLocationCoordinate2D satcoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, s);
CLLocationCoordinate2D dishcoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pinlat, pinlon);

locations[0] = satcoord;
locations[1] = dishcoord;

NSLog(@"satcoord %f,%f", locations[0].latitude, locations[0].longitude);
NSLog(@"dishcord %f,%f", locations[1].latitude, locations[1].longitude);

// Create the polyline based on the array of points.   
routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locations count:1];

[routeLineView setNeedsDisplay];

}
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{

routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;
return routeLineView;

}
```

Comment: routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locations count:1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:locations count:1];
```

should have been "count:2" instead of "count:1"